# Malformed JSON using RxJava and retrofit

Tags: java, android, gson, rx-java, rx-android

I want take some data from a JSON, but the gson is giving an error. I want to know how can i solve this?

I'm using dagger2(this part is 100% ok and working) and rxJava(this part is calling always the onError method).

**My model:**

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public class GradeModel {

//I'm using lombok to generate getters and setters.

    @SerializedName("grade")
    @Expose
    private DecimalFormat grades;

    @SerializedName("grades")
    @Expose
    private GradeModel listGrades;

    private String matter;
    private int fault;

}
```

**My JSON:**

```
grades: [

    {
        "class": "math"
        "grade": 4.5,
        "next_dates":[
            {
                "exam": "03/03/2017",
                "homework": "03/03/2017"
            }

        ]

    }

    {
        "class": "port"
        "grade": 8,
        "next_dates":[
            {
                "exam": "03/05/2017",
                "homework": "03/03/2017"
            }

        ]

    }

]
```

**My Response:**

```
public class GradeResponse {

    @Inject
    Retrofit retrofit;

    @Inject
    MainPresenter mainPresenter;

    public void getGradeRx() {

        MyApplication.getMainComponent().injectIntoGradeResponse(this);// informando ao dagger sobre o uso de um component e a necessidade de injetar dependência

        Subscription getGrade = retrofit
                .create(GradeService.class)
                .getGrade()
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .map(model -> {
                    // transform model
                        return model.getListGrades();
                })
                .subscribe(new Observer<GradeModel>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted() {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(Throwable e) {
                        Log.i(TAG, "saporra vai me matar ainda");
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNext(GradeModel grades) {
                        Log.i(TAG, "caralhoooooo " + grades.getGrades());
                        //mainPresenter.setListGrades(grades);
                    }
                });
    }
}
```

**My retrofit:**

```
@Module
public class RetrofitModule {
    @Provides
    @PerActivity
    Gson provideGson() {
        GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
        //gsonBuilder.setFieldNamingPolicy(FieldNamingPolicy.LOWER_CASE_WITH_UNDERSCORES);
        return gsonBuilder.create();
    }
    @Provides
    @PerActivity
    public OkHttpClient provideHttpClient() {
        return new OkHttpClient().newBuilder().build();
    }
    @Provides
    @PerActivity
    public Retrofit provideRetrofit(Gson gson, OkHttpClient okHttpClient) {
        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .client(okHttpClient)
                //converts Retrofit response into Observable
                .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.create())
                .build();
        return retrofit;
    }
}
```

**My Service:**

```
public interface GradeService {

    @GET("grades_json.json")
    Observable<GradeModel> getGrade();
}
```

**The Error:**

> com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Use
>   JsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept malformed JSON at line 1 column
>   1 path $

Comment: Remove `grades:` from the JSON and it is correct

Comment: Without remove grades from the JSON has something that i could do?

Comment: Why can you not edit `grades_json.json`? It **is not** proper JSON.

Comment: You're missing some commas and JSON always has quoted keys for any value. http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: Because is not my file, i copied that json and put online without the "grades:" and still the same onError method, nothing changed.

Comment: Because it still isn't correct... `"class": "math"` is missing a comma, `"class": "port"` is missing a comma. You're also missing a comma between the objects of the array. Only once those are fixed will Gson help you parse anything

Comment: I did this: @cricket_007

 `{
 
"grades":[

{
  "class": "math",
  "grade": "4.5"
 
 },
 
 {
  "class": "port",
  "grade": "8"
 
 }

]

}`

Still doesn't work.

Comment: That doesn't match your Java class. You have `DecimalFormat grades` and `GradeModel listGrades`... And the JSON would contain `"grades"` and `"grade"`... I don't even know how a `DecimalFormat` would be serialized...

Comment: When i change decimal format to double still doesn't work. I want those numbers at JSON. The error don't changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) `grades: [` is not part of valid JSON. Remove `grades:` and leave the `[` if you want to parse a JSON **array**.

Then, your Gson model is wrong. You have `"grades"` and `"grade"`, not `"grade"`, `"next_dates"`, and `"class"`.

This is also **two** objects.

```
{                    // One Object here
    "class": "math", 
    "grade": 4.5,
    "next_dates":[
        {            // Second object here
            "exam": "03/03/2017",
            "homework": "03/03/2017"
        }
    ]
}
```

So, your Java classes would be something like

```
public class GradeDate {
    private String exam, homework;
}

public class GradeModel {
    private String class;
    private Double grade;
    private List<GradeDate> nextDates;
}
```

Then, your JSON is still missing some commas to separate the values in the outer array.